# How to disable long double in boost::math?

Tags: c++, boost, long-double

I have c++ source file, example.cpp, using some boost::math functions.

My boost library is also built.

To disable long double in boost::math, I did the following:

```
g++ -DBOOST_MATH_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS example.cpp -I<boost_header> -L<boost.*.so>
```

My question is whether do I need to rebuild boost library with `-DBOOST_MATH_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS`? Or, in other words, did the boost library differ with and without macro `BOOST_MATH_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there might be a difference. However, in practice, there will usually not be:

Boot Math docs: [Building a Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/building.html#math_toolkit.building.building_a_library_shared_dynami)

> The first thing you need to ask yourself is "Do I need to build
> anything at all?" as the bulk of this library is header only: meaning
> you can use it just by #including the necessary header(s).
>
> For most simple uses, including a header (or few) is best for compile
> time and program size.
>
> Refer to C99 and C++ TR1 C-style Functions for pros and cons of using
> the TR1 components as opposed to the header only ones.
>
> The only time you need to build the library is if you want to use the
> extern "C" functions declared in <boost/math/tr1.hpp>.

Since tr1.hpp does in fact use the `BOOST_MATH_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS` macro, so yes there will probably be a relevant difference.

In fact from a quick scan it looks like auto-linking (on MSVC) is only caused when the preprocessor condition is **not** defined. Which implies that building the library is completely  unnecessary when the symbol is defined. Try *not* linking to the library to check that assumption:

```
g++ -DBOOST_MATH_NO_LONG_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS example.cpp -I<boost_header>
```

### Post Scriptum

The only use of the define in libs/math/src is in `boost_nexttoward` and `boost_nexttowardf`.

So unless  you use these, there should be no issue.

In all of Boost 1.77 the only libraries that mention these  `boost/math/tr1.hpp` are Multiprecision and  Units - but it looks like they took great care to NOT expand macros and never explicitly call the `boost_*` symbols.

All in all, you're only looking for *direct* calls to `[boost_]nexttoward[f]` in your own code.